# Price removal from Product Page with .xml or .php OR stop GOOGLE indexing it

Tags: price, product-prices, rich-snippets

**Hey everyone!**

I am wondering if anyone could help me with this as I have been struggling for quite a bit now.

I have a magento 1.9 web store where all the prices are hidden with CSS (brochure website).

**Problem?**

Google still indexes rich snippets of the products and spits the "dummy prices" to Search Engine Results Page.

**I am a fresher to .php and .xml.**

Dont get overwhelmed with info here, just want to make it informative.

**What have I figured out ?**

That the **layout** of the product page is in: **theme_name/default/template/page/1column.phtml**

1) That is where the product page container is defined as:

```
<div class="col-main"> 
           <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?> 
           <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?> 
</div>
```

2) Then in **page.xml** I find “content”:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
 </block>
```

3) And in **catalog.xml** line 189 I find

```
   <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

Where under it I find:

- Product.info.media
- Product.info.upsell
- Product.info.additional
- Product.attributes
- Product.info.addto
- Product.info.addtocart

…and couple of more blocks…

4) Inspect element looks like:

[image]

I know the div **product-type-data** is being pulled through from:
App/design/frontend/theme_name/default/template/catalog/product/**view.phtml**

```
   <div <?php if ($useRichSnippets) echo $helperSnippets->getOfferItemscope(); ?>>

                <div class="product-type-data<?php echo $productTypeClasses; ?>"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?></div>

                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); ?>

                <?php echo $priceProperties; ?>

            </div> <?php //end: offers ?>
```

5) The **price-box** div is being pulled through from:
Base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml *(if you need full code let me know)*

```
<?php if ($price): ?>
        <div class="price-box">
```

**Can anyone help me understand:**

a)  What would be the solution to remove the **price block** or what needs to be done that google would stop indexing the price?

b)  Could I comment out the **product-type-data** in **view.phtml** and would it work?

**Any comments and remarks would be highly appreciated**

Many thanks ++

(additional image just in case it helps)

[image]

---

### UPDATE - GOT IT SORTED

i went to the view.phtml file and edited this

from line 347 removed " `<div <?php if ($useRichSnippets) echo $helperSnippets->getOfferItemscope(); ?>>`   " - this line removes `<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemprop="http://schema.org/offer" style=" content:display;>` on front end

from line 353 removed   `<?php echo $priceProperties; ?>`     THIS LINE ACTUALLY GIVES LINES ON THE FRONT END: `"META ITEMPROP="PRICEcURRENCY" CONTENT="GBP">` and `<META ITEMPROP="PRICE" CONTENT="992">`

from line 355 removed "  `</div> <?php //end: offers ?>`  "  THIS IS JUST A CLOSING DIV FOR THE 347 LINE.

thanks everyone who looked

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could comment out/ remove "product-type-data" and that would stop the rich snippets.  you can test this here:
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

But just because it not a rich snippet and you as still showing the price in the html code but hidding it was css, google might still read the price from the code, know what it is without the rich snippets markup and show it in the serps (but I would guess that this is unlikely)